# Empty string check on Input element value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why isn't my empty string check working as expected on an `HTMLInputElement` value property after trim? Problem code in `storeOnEnter` function. The goal is to only set new state when the input is empty.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ItemEditor extends Component {
    state = {
        showInput: true,
        itemDescription: ''
    }

    storeOnEnter = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.key !== 'Enter') return;

        const input = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        if (!input.value.trim) return;

        this.setState({itemDescription: input.value, showInput: false})
    }

    switchToInput = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        this.setState({showInput: true});
    }

    render() {
        let input = <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.storeOnEnter} defaultValue={this.state.itemDescription}/>
        let label = <label style={{userSelect: 'none'}} onDoubleClick={(e) => this.switchToInput(e)}>{this.state.itemDescription}</label>

        return this.state.showInput ? input : label;
    }
}

export default ItemEditor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim` is a function. That's why `!input.value.trim` is always truthy. Use `!input.value.trim()` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: Doh. Might have to stick to Kotlin after hours, stupid lack of sleep mistake wow... thank you

Comment: It happened to the best :)